# In Eberron do Elves dream and did Giants create them?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, elf

Did the Giants find the primitive Elves and civilized and enslaved them or did they create them, like they did their own version of Warforged?

I think I heard somewhere (probably The Dreaming Dark Trilogy) that they created them to resist the Quori and that's why Elves do not sleep or dream. On the other hand, in other sources ([Player's Handbook 3.5](http://dndtools.eu/races/players-handbook-v35--6/elf--2/)) I read that when Elves trance, they dream in a sort of mental exercises way. I guess that still doesn't mean their mind goes to Dal Quor or does it? I'm confused.

So it's basically 2 questions wrapped up in one. The dream question is more pressing/important for me now, thanks. (3.5 lore please)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can’t find any suggestion that the giants had anything to do with the origin of the elves; the elves seem to predate the giants’ rise to power, actually existing during the Age of Demons, at which time the “lesser races” (i.e. not demon or dragon, apparently including at least the elves, giants, goblins, and orcs) simply tried to avoid getting killed in the war between demons and dragons.

After the couatls sacrificed themselves to end that Age, the giants were able to rise to power in Xen’drik using dragon-taught magic, ushering the Age of Giants.

The giant empire *then* enslaved elves, and thus “inadvertently” raised them up out of their primitive state, teaching them magic and the like. Towards the end of, or just after, the war with the quori, the elves revolted. The giants were going to put this down using the same cataclysmic magic they’d used against the quori, but the dragons came and crushed them, instead. An elven prophet/hero named Aeren, among other things, foresaw this end and signaled that the elves should flee Xen’drik before it happened.

Those elves named the island they fled to “Aeren’s Rest” or Aerenal, and referred to themselves as the Aereni. Aeren had sacrificed himself during the exodus, but not before figuring out how to do the whole undying thing, so he became the first undying councilor.

The drow, of course, stayed in Xen’drik. Simply based on the fact that all elves from Xen’drik are drow and no Aerenal elves are drow, it seems likely that the actual distinction between “elf” and “drow” happened after the exodus, *probably* during or immediately after during the dragonfire-purge.

However, *Secrets of Xen’drik* does have this:

> According to one legend, the Sul’at giants created the drow by binding dark forces to normal elves

The Sul’at League was a series of fire giant city-states, founded by the first fire giant Adaxus, who got that way through some fiendish pact. Or so legend has it, anyway. This is the only mention I can find of giants manipulating an elven race. That said, it doesn’t seem to jive with the facts, which calls that legend into doubt. It seems unlikely that *every single drow* would choose to stay and *every single elf* would choose to leave.

The elven trance is different from sleep, and their “dreams” are different as well. I am still searching for information about whether or not these dreams are similar enough that they still go to Dal’Quor in spirit while they trance.

Unfortunately, I have so far looked through *Eberron Campaign Setting*, *Secrets of Xen’drik*, *Secrets of Sarlona*, *Magic of Eberron*, *Races of Eberron*, and *Player’s Guide to Eberron*, all without finding any reference to elven dreaming or lack thereof, much less whether or not the giants were responsible for it. I didn’t read those books cover-to-cover, but anything that sounded like it might even possibly have the reference, I checked. I’m running out of even remotely likely suspects.

Comment: @Simanos Ah, I did not think to check *dream* or *nightmare* specifically. You are probably correct that they don’t dream. If the giants had a hand in that, it was a later modification of the race rather than as part of their creation, but I haven’t yet found anything saying that they did. It’s possible it was that very property that led to elves being so useful to the giants... though I think the slavery started before the quori showed up, so I don’t know.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit vague. Only thing I could find was http://eberronunlimited.wikidot.com/elf . That site usually copies the books, but I looked at my Races of Eberron and ECS books and I couldn't find the phrase: "Elves do not sleep, as members of the other common races do. Instead, an elf meditates in a deep trance for 4 hours a day. An elf resting in this fashion gains the same benefit that a human does from 8 hours of sleep. While meditating, an elf dreams, though these dreams are actually mental exercises that have become reflexive through years of practice."

Comment: http://dndtools.eu/races/players-handbook-v35--6/elf--2/ has the same phrase, hmm, the http://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#elves doesn't , but that's a setting issue maybe? Dndtools site says to look at my player's handbook 3.5, I'll get back to you... Yup the phrase is in there, does it apply to Eberron?

Comment: @Simanos Huh, that’s interesting. The SRD doesn’t include that line because it’s not open content (and dnd-tools does because they infringe on WotC’s copyright). I’ll have to dig more in my Eberron books to see if they ever address that specifically...

Comment: BTW http://eberron.wikia.com/wiki/Eberron_Timeline says the Age of Monsters came after the Age of Giants, they are not the same age, right? The Giant Empire enslaved the Elves before the Age of Monsters and the goblin empire.

Comment: @Simanos Err... derp? Not doing so well on this question, huh? Anyway, I have so far looked through *Eberron Campaign Setting*, *Secrets of Sarlona*, *Magic of Eberron*, *Races of Eberron*, and *Player’s Guide to Eberron*, all without finding *any* reference to elven dreaming or lack thereof, much less whether or not the giants were responsible for it. I didn’t read those books cover-to-cover, but anything that sounded like it might even possibly have the reference, I checked. I’m running out of even remotely likely suspects.

Comment: I asked the friend who originated this story and (our old DM) and he said he read about the Giants modifying "some" elves to resist the Quori in the Dreaming Dark Trilogy. Maybe it was only the Drow, he can't recall. Anyway, I've decided I'm going to house-rule this in my campaign and seeing as I already sent the elf player to Dal Quor along with the other 3 players, I am forced to houserule that elves do indeed go there in their mental-exercises/dreams.

Comment: @Simanos Even Kalashtar could *plane shift* or similar to Dal Quor, if the elf’s gone there physically. But yeah, I don’t think it’s a particularly important point; the books certainly don’t bring it up. Anyway, I don’t have access to any of the novels. You might add that comment as your own answer for someone in the future (comments will likely be deleted).

Comment: I've added it to the question. I sent the players to Dal Quor using their dreams not plane-shift. They slept near an Eldritch Machine with a "dream net".